# A new file in the folder event

Tags: c#, file, events, file-io, directory

Can someone please help me to understand how to build a software that run 24/7 that listen to a specific folder (ex. C:\Actions) and each time I place a new file in that folder, the software needs to read and processing it.

If there isn't files in the folder the software shouldn't do nothing only to wait to the next file to come.

Example of the file (action1.txt) content (1+1)

The software is processing (1+1), saving the answer(2) to anther folder and delete the file(action1.txt) from the "C:\Actions\" folder.

I know how to read the file and process it..

I'm having difficulty to understand how to trigger the software only when there is new file in the folder and how to run the software for 24/7 without using so much memory or causing to memory leakage…

Till now I've used it in the primitive way of looping endless and each 60 sec (Sleep) I'm checking the folder for new files. That's so useless and not so effective.

I'll be happy if someone can help me to understand how to make it more effective..

thank you very much

Comment: Please, do not include a languge tag in a title unless it wouldn't made sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Understand this class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx and you are ready to go. It has the needed events.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new in here, how do I mark it as answered?

Answer (score 9):

Use the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

An example from that page:

```
    // Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    watcher.Path = "C:\\Actions";
    /* Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
       the renaming of files or directories. */
    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
       | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
    // Only watch text files.
    watcher.Filter = "*.txt";

    // Add event handlers.
    watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);

    // Begin watching.
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

And the changed event:

```
// Define the event handlers. 
private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
   Console.WriteLine("File: " +  e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
}
```

There are some things you need to watch out for when using this class though.  It does not work well on network drives/UNC paths.  Also if you paste a lot of files to the directory, it will overfill the [buffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.internalbuffersize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and you might not get events for every file that is added to the folder.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Class:

> Listens to the file system change notifications and raises events when a directory, or file in a directory, changes.
>
> **Changed**   Occurs when a file or directory in the specified Path is changed.
>
> **Created**   Occurs when a file or directory in the specified Path is created.