# duplicated files show in listbox from folder WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

i have a problem where if i get my files from folder (gedaan)
it duplicates and put the files from the folders in my listbox agian.

i just want it to check if there are new files in my folder

this is my code to get files from a folder

```
        DirectoryInfo dinfo = new 
        DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\nour\Desktop\Gedaan");
        FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.DOCX");
        foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
        {
            LB2.Items.Add(file.Name);
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A new file in the folder event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21934817/a-new-file-in-the-folder-event)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are adding all files again.

You either have to clear your collection before adding all files again:

```
DirectoryInfo dinfo = new 
DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\nour\Desktop\Gedaan");
FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.DOCX");
LB2.Items.Clear();
foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
{
    LB2.Items.Add(file.Name);
}
```

Or you have to exclude duplicate files:

```
DirectoryInfo dinfo = new 
DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\nour\Desktop\Gedaan");
IEnumerable<FileInfo> Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.DOCX").Where(file => !LB2.Items.Contains(file.Name));
foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
{
    LB2.Items.Add(file.Name);
}
```

Another approach would be to change the type of `LB2.Items` to the type `HashSet<string>`. `HashSet<T>` is is a collection that contains no duplicate elements. Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1

Comment: Ive used my common sense and did the first one before u posted, thanks anyways! marked as answer